# Is it possible to sort controls inside flowpanel without using .add() and .clear() by clicking id or name etc

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[Application Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLm9Y.png)

I tried searching all over from the internet if this kind of thing is possible but I didn't find any that solve my problem..

Here is my code for ... but this code keep on adding another usercontrols to my panel...

```
 Sub sorbyID()
        pnList.Controls.Clear()
        connect()
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
        Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM clientinfo order by id desc"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            Dim c As Control1 = New Control1
            If dr.Read Then
                c.Dock = DockStyle.Top
                c.lblID.Text = dr("ID")
                c.lblName.Text = dr("lname") & ", " & dr("fName")
                c.lblPlan.Text = dr("plan")
                c.lblIPadd.Text = dr("ipAdd")
                c.lblMac.Text = dr("Mac")
                c.lblBrgy.Text = dr("brgy")

                pnList.Controls.Add(c)

            End If

        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: maybe clear the controls in the current pnList first e.g. `pnList.Controls.Clear()`

Comment: it does clear and sort the usercontrols but it takes 3 seconds to clear and add it in my flowpanel

Comment: that sounds like another issue to ask another question about, but you can't keep adding controls and expect it to sort without clearing it.

Comment: is that it sir..  but is it possible to sort it without using .add() and .clear

Comment: I can't say without knowing the implementation of the user control, but I'm guessing no.

Comment: It would be good if you could explain **how** your application **should** behave. Just saying *"it is not doing what I expect"* simply not good enoughAnd how can you even do this `For i As Integer = 0 To 10` if you don't even know your reader has 11 records or any at all? And when you say, *"by clicking id or name"*, it is not clear, **what**  are you clicking on?

Comment: thank you for everybody feedbacks.
I am able to solve my problem by using .add and .clear
and to load it faster I use double buffering